# Is there a faster way than this numpy code for finding the unique adjacent pairs in a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a 2D numpy array representing a biological cell segmentation mask. In other words, this array indicates the pixels in a separate 2D microscope image that belong to different cells, so wherever a "1" appears in the array, those positions in the image are part of the with ID 1, where "2" appears they belong to cell ID 2, etc. When there's a 0, there is no cell in that part of the image. I want to find the cells that are adjacent to each other. I've come up with the code below, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this, as I need to run this on a loop for hundreds of masks and it currently takes a few hours total with this solution:

```
#Get the horizontal adjacent pairs
v = mask.flatten()
x = np.column_stack([v[:-1], v[1:]])
#Get the vertical adjacent pairs
v = mask.T.flatten()
y = np.column_stack([v[:-1], v[1:]])
#Just keep unique pairs
pairs = np.unique(np.vstack([x, y]), axis=0)
#Drop pairs with no cell or the same cell
pairs[(pairs[:,0] != 0) & (pairs[:,1] != 0) & (pairs[:,0] != pairs[:,1])]
```

Edit: I just realized this code isn't even correct as the use of flatten will cause cells on one border to be adjacent to cells on the opposite border.

Comment: So you're looking for transitions like 11111122222 that don't have intervening zeros?  What about vertical adjacencies?

Comment: Yes, exactly. From that example I would want to get the pair (1, 2). Vertical adjacencies also need to be considered.

Comment: You could add a border of  0  around your image.  That would solve the wraparound issue.